# Svcutil.exe The following policy assertions were not imported

Tags: wcf

I am trying to use svcutil.exe to create a proxyclass, config for a service.
wsdl: https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsdl
Service URL: https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService

But I am getting this error:

```
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 x86 tools.

C:\Windows\system32>svcutil.exe https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService?wsd
l
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHServi
ce?wsdl' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Warning: The following Policy Assertions were not Imported:
  XPath://wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://org/emedny/mhs/']/wsdl:bindi
ng[@name='MHS']
  Assertions:
    <dpe:summary xmlns:dpe='http://www.datapower.com/extensions'>..</dpe:summary
>
    <sp:SupportingTokens xmlns:sp='http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securityp
olicy/200702'>..</sp:SupportingTokens>



Generating files...
C:\Windows\system32\MHService.cs
C:\Windows\system32\output.config

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Although it generated 2 files, the ouptput.config has nothing but some text telling us that binding details are not imported.

Please suggest